# Is there a way to display prompt before menu in this Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there a way to get the following Bash script to display each of the two prompts
*before* its select menu instead of after it?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS3='Copy database to which server? '
options=("debug" "dev" "prod" "Quit")
select server in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $server in
        "debug")
            break
            ;;
        "dev")
            break
            ;;
        "prod")
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "Quitting"
            exit 1
            ;;
        *) echo "Invalid option";;
    esac
done

PS3='Reuse existing user data or get fresh data? '
options=("existing" "fresh" "Quit")
select data in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $data in
        "existing")
            break
            ;;
        "fresh")
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "Quitting"
            exit 1
            ;;
        *) echo "Invalid option";;
    esac
done

echo "You chose "$server" and "$data
exit 1
```

Comment: just change `PS3=` to `echo ` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... You can write text to the user at any time with `echo`:

```
echo 'Copy database to which server?'
options=("debug" "dev" "prod" "Quit")
select server in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $server in
        "debug")
            break
            ;;
        "dev")
            break
            ;;
        "prod")
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "Quitting"
            exit 1
            ;;
        *) echo "Invalid option";;
    esac
done
```

This would give you:

```
Copy database to which server?
1) debug
2) dev
3) prod
4) Quit
#?
```

Comment: Yea, I thought of that but I don't like the "#?" prompt.  It's kind of ugly.  Unfortunately, my Bash kung-fu is weak.

Comment: Use `PS3='> '` to set the prompt to what you want then